# Blender crashes when manipulating a large number of vertices with proportional editing enabled

Tags: mesh, selection-tools

I have a sculpture with 250,000 vertices and I select the head (70,000 vertices) I would like to rotate the head 12 degrees around the z axis with proportional editing enabled so the neck and upper torso twist with it, when I do this Blender crashes on my computer. Is there any way around this problem? One way that seems to work is to deselect 95% of the vertices on the head, the trouble is I only know how to do this one vertice at a time!

Comment: Maybe you coud add an armature to the model and use it to move the head. Then you could apply the armature modifier.

Comment: why don't you use bones to move a head?

Comment: I could do that in this example but I run into this problem constantly when I want to add small changes to a sculpture that I have almost finished

Comment: try to activate VBOs in user preferences, system tab

Comment: I tried that and blender crashed again, I've no idea what a VBO is!

Comment: Maybe try with lattice modifier?

Comment: VBO means Vertex Buffer Object. It's a method use in openGL (viewport) to store geometry information. This option can make the viewport faster. Not enough in your case. Did u deactivate any subsurf/multires visibility?

Comment: Yeah! a lattice modifier would suit my work flow in most cases, this one included but I would still like to be able to use the proportional editing tool if possible, I come from the real world of clay and wax where you can do these things no problem and I am new to Blender.

Comment: You also could try to move the most part of the head without Proportionnal Editing and finish the job hiding the moved vertices, selecting the neck and move it with PE. This will move far less vertices.

Comment: That would work too but I would still love to be able to select a bunch of vertices then deselect 95% of them, if that is not possible and there is no other way to use proportional editing I will be content to use a combination of all these ideas to do the final tweaks

Comment: Do you know the "C", "B" and Ctrl+left click selection modes?

Comment: COnsider getting more RAM for your computer as well...

Comment: OK I've got it sorted, I did a random select set to 1% and then deselected with C all the vertices except for those of the head.The head rotated with PE with barely a lag!

Comment: good to know! thx for sharing

Answer (score 3):

It would probably be better to use a lattice modifier but if you wish to deselect vertices the following method seems to work for this example. Select the area you wish to manipulate then go to the 3D viewport header choose: Select > Random, go to the bottom of the tool shelf: enter Percent> 99% (for example) and Action> Deselect.You may need to add a few vertices to fill in any gaps. You can now manipulate using the proportional editing tool set to a largeish fall off without unwelcome lag or crashes.